# Подскажите ресурс по изучению UML

Tags: uml

Есть ли какие-небудь книги, статьи, может видео курсы

Comment: https://www.uml.org/

Comment: Советую книгу Крэга Лармана "Применение UML и шаблонов проектирования". Это не учебник UML, но почитать полезно.